# How to use wp_extract_urls() in WordPress if I want to find NOT unique links?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to use wp_extract_urls() in WordPress if I want to find NOT unique links? I just want to count all the links in my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is likely to create a new function in your functions.php file that excludes the `array_unique()` part of the existing function. Something like this should work -

```
function wp_extract_all_urls( $content ) {
    preg_match_all(
        "#([\"']?)("
            . "(?:([\w-]+:)?//?)"
            . "[^\s()<>]+"
            . "[.]"
            . "(?:"
                . "\([\w\d]+\)|"
                . "(?:"
                    . "[^`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>«»“”‘’\s]|"
                    . "(?:[:]\d+)?/?"
                . ")+"
            . ")"
        . ")\\1#",
        $content,
        $post_links
    );

    $post_links = array_map( 'html_entity_decode', $post_links[2] );

    return array_values( $post_links );
}
```